# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'app' before initialization

Tags: node.js, npm, initialization

I have this Problem when I start my Backend, I want to test the post request in Postmann but I have this error, how can I fix it?

this is my code for `Server.js` [image: Server . j s]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const app = express()` Should come before your middlewares... `app.use(...)`

Also make sure to connect your mongo database before your `app` initialization not after `app.listen(...)`. Your application should depend on your database, throw error if database didn't connect, all this should happen in `try{}catch(){}`

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `app.use` methods before initializing app.

Just move `const app = express()` before `app.use`.

Answer (score 0):

The app variable is used before you declare it. Move your `const app = express();` upward. Like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```